# geom_smooth does not plot a line for my data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with the following data

```
my2016.regression.dataframe <- structure(list(Economy_Directorate = structure(c(9L, 1L, 18L, 
11L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("20128895", "25392278", "26802176", 
"33214069", "34194316", "34863777", "34867843", "36497785", "37280694", 
"37411816", "44460126", "45484123", "47463441", "48354697", "57954259", 
"60187650", "65135916", "67317188"), class = "factor"), People_Directorate = structure(c(12L, 
14L, 17L, 16L, 13L, 15L), .Label = c("20128895", "25392278", 
"26802176", "33214069", "34194316", "34863777", "34867843", "36497785", 
"37280694", "37411816", "44460126", "45484123", "47463441", "48354697", 
"57954259", "60187650", "65135916", "67317188"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Economy_Directorate", 
"People_Directorate"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the following  code to plot it. it plotts the points, but it does not plot the lm  .
Could you help me why it does not plot the the lm in the geom_smooth

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data =my2016.regression.dataframe )+
  geom_point(aes(y=Economy_Directorate,x=People_Directorate))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",aes(y=Economy_Directorate,x=People_Directorate),
              fill="orange",colour="red")
```

Regards,

Comment: Works for me, which versions of `ggplot2` and `R` are you using?

Comment: RStdio Version 1.1.383   
ggplot2 version 2.2.1

Comment: Just a small remark: you can set the `aes()` in the main `ggplot` call. Than you won't need to set it twice in `geom_point` and in `geom_smooth`.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'm using Rstudio 1.0.143, R version 3.4.1 and ggplot 2.2.1. Do you get the error bars and only lack the red line, or neither orange bars and red line?

Comment: please do not add data as simple text. use `dput(my2016.regression.dataframe)` then paste the ouput into the question. Otherwise we cannot diagnose any issues that are due to the format of your data. Also, this makes it easier for us to import your data, and if you are asking for help it is only polite to make it as easy as possible for people by allowing them to replicate your problem with only a cut and paste of some complete code (including `library` calls).

Comment: @LAP neither the error bar or the red line

Comment: @dww thanks for your comment as I am new to r ,by the way I have modified the actual post  and posted the output as u mentioned

Comment: @AdielLoinger thanks for ur comment , good observation

Comment: As I suspected - your number columns are factors. Convert to numeric and all should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your columns to numeric types. They are currently factors:

```
my2016.regression.dataframe$Economy_Directorate = as.numeric(as.character(my2016.regression.dataframe$Economy_Directorate))
my2016.regression.dataframe$People_Directorate = as.numeric(as.character(my2016.regression.dataframe$People_Directorate))

ggplot(data = my2016.regression.dataframe) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Economy_Directorate,x=People_Directorate))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",aes(y=Economy_Directorate,x=People_Directorate),
              fill="orange",colour="red")
```

[image]